# Rupee symbol in angular4 pipes

Tags: angular

I tried to show rupee symbol in angular4 pipes

```
{{amount | currency:"₹":0}}
```

but this is not working. Is there any other solution.

Comment: I am working with Angular4 pipes, not Angular1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems with your implementation of the currency pipe, it should be:

```
{{amount | currency: 'INR':true}}
```

As a warning from the **[docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)**:

> WARNING: this pipe uses the Internationalization API which is not yet available in all browsers and may require a polyfill

Comment: `Warning: the currency pipe has been changed in Angular v5. The symbolDisplay option (third parameter) is now a string instead of a boolean. The accepted values are "code", "symbol" or "symbol-narrow".`

Comment: for latest angular `true` is not required ie: `{{amount | currency: 'INR'}}`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for Angular 4+ versions:

```
{{amount | currency: 'INR'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

currency:'INR':'symbol':'1.2-2'

Use this ,will work fine..If you want in different currency just change type//Ex:Replace INR by USD